# OpenMP implementations in VC++ 2008, 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp

Depending on implementation, OMP can be quite useful to parallelize fairly arbitrary bits of code - e.g a parallel section inside a method that calls two independent methods - or it can be bad. It depends on how threads are created/cached, I think.

How does the VC++ 2008 implementation work? And is the 2010 implementation significantly different in terms of features and performance/flexibility?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenMP implementation in both VS2008 and VS2010 is compliant with the version 2.0 specification.  There are some annotations in the MSDN Library but it doesn't go deep.  Best place to look for detailed specifications is at the [openmp.org site](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/).